# Is there a cleaner way to handle Express rendering differently for AJAX posts vs HTML form posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, express

I have an HTML form that's pretty basic, and I'm in the process of using jQuery's AJAX post functionality to get some info back depending upon whether a database insertion succeeded or failed.

My code is currently doing something like the following, I only set the `ajax` post variable to `true` when doing posting via AJAX to differentiate the origin.

```
app.post("/mypath", function (req, res) {
    var post = req.body;

    if (post.ajax) {
        console.log(post.ajax, "posting as ajax");
    }

    if (post.ajax) {
        res.json({data: "Woah! You posted as ajax."});
    }
    else {
        // If posting via HTML form, send the user where they need to go
        res.redirect("someview");
    }
});
```

My real concern is that I don't want the end user to see a page with JSON in plain text, but I want some of that JSON data when I have JavaScript support in order to notify the user about success/failure.

**Is there any way I can make this cleaner?** I have 3 places where I'd have to have the conditional rendering in that one application route.

I'm using Express 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. As long as your client-side code sets the `Accept` header appropriately, you can use [`res.format`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.format), e.g.:

```
res.format({
    html: function() {
        res.redirect('someview');
    },
    json: function() {
        res.json({data: "You expected JSON? You got JSON!"});
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this will do it, I'll just have to play around with it to make all my async code work properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post](http://codetunnel.com/how-to-toggle-jade-layout-in-express-for-nodejs/) I wrote a while back. I wrote a helper that will automatically render a full or partial view in express.

The key is to create jade views like this: (unfortunately Jade views are pre-compiled and you can't pass a variable to `include`, nor can you conditionally call `extends`, so we need this "glue" file. You'll see why.)

```
// home_full.jade

extends layout  
block content  
    include home
```

It extends the layout file and includes a partial view. This view acts as the glue between the real view and the layout file. These intermediary views always end in "_full.jade".

Next I created my own little middleware function that adds the helper to `req`.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {  
    res.renderView = function (viewName, viewModel) {
        res.render(viewName + req.xhr ? null : '_full', viewModel);
        next();
    };
});
```

It's called `renderView` and it does the xhr logic for us. Instead of rendering views with `req.render`...

```
res.render('home' + req.xhr ? null : '_full', viewModel);
```

...you just call `req.renderView` and pass in the view name:

```
res.renderView('home');
```

Now if the request is a full page request then we'll send back the fully compiled view, layout and all. If the ajax request header is set (which most client-side libraries like JQuery and others kindly do for you) then we'll send back only the partial view and let the client populate the appropriate area on the page :)

PS - If you need to send back views along with other JSON data you can use my extended version of the helper function. Example:

```
res.renderView = function (viewName, viewModel) {
    if (!req.xhr) {
        res.render(viewName + '_full', viewModel);
    } else {
        res.render(viewName, viewModel, function (err, view) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json({
                title: viewModel.title || "Untitled | CodeTunnel.com",
                bannerText: viewModel.bannerText || "CodeTunnel.com",
                view: view,
                url: req.url
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Obviously you'd tweak the `res.json` call to match your own needs. In my implementation above I needed a JSON object that contained the page title, the text to display in the page banner, the view markup as a string property on our object, and the request URL. I would then use this data on the client to both render the partial view, as well as update the page title and other things on the client.

Comment: I think is just far too complicated for what I'm trying to do.